# PHP E_WARNING being shown despite php.ini

Tags: php, errors, php.ini

I'm on OS X. I just upgraded to High Sierra 10.13.x from Sierra 10.12.x, and thus to PHP 7 from PHP 5. I suddenly started getting PHP Warning errors displayed in the browser. (It's fine that PHP errors get displayed in the browser, but I didn't want to see warnings.) No amount of tinkering with php.ini would fix this. Eventually I realized that the problem wasn't with php.ini, but with Wordpress itself. (Warnings in non-Wordpress PHP files weren't displayed, as should be the case.) It appears that something in Wordpress is overriding my `error_reporting` settings in php.ini.

How can I stop Wordpress from doing this?

Comment: Fixed it! Putting `error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING);` at the top of functions.php did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your wp-config.php file for WP_DEBUG constants?

```
//enable debug
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

//save to file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

//show in browser
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG for more details.

Comment: is it an answer or a question? ;)

Comment: @Pabamato I did, I did! I just added those things to wp_config and set them all to false, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Was an answer @mark-kaplun, sorry if causes confussion.
Megabulk I assume you placed the code before the "ABSPATH" definition, you can try force the value with php: 
    ini_set('display_errors',0);